$R$-symmetry, commutators and charges in supersymmetry
In my lectures in supersymmetry, i have written the following statement about $R$-symmetry

It is special since it does not commute with supersymmetry. Instead, it obeys $ \left[ R, Q_a \right] = -Q_a $ and $ \left[ R, \bar{Q}_{\dot{a}} \right] =  \bar{Q}_{\dot{a}}  $ this means that the $R$-charge of the boson and the fermion in a chiral supermultiplet necessarily differ. Concretely if $ R[\phi] = r $ is tbe charge of the boson, then $ R[\psi] = r-1 $ is the charge of the fermion and $ R[F] = r - 2 $ is the charge of the superfield

How exactly does he arrive at this result? What is the mathematical argument for this?

Hint. Those commutators tell you that $Q$ is a lowering operator for $R$ and $\bar{Q}$ is a raising operator.
